# 3 Hours video opens as 3 minutes [ffmpeg][vegas][Windows]

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a mp4 video that is 3:55:00 long. However, when I try to edit it with Vegas 13 or ffmpeg, the softwares only find the first 00:03:16 part.

I tried to search for similar questions, but did not find any answers.

Video details(Windows explorer):
Length: 03:55:00
Res: 1280x720
Data rate:1342 kbps
Total bitrate: 1408 kbps
Frame rate: 25 f/s

Audio
Bit rate:65 kbps
Channels: 2(stereo)
Audio sample rate: 44.1 kHz

Video details(Vegas, ffmpeg):
Format: AVC
ffmpeg compatible_brands:  isomiso2avc1mp41

I tried using ffmpeg to convert it to a regular mp4. Unfortunately it only finds the first 3:16 minutes too.

**UPDATE**

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i origin.mp4 -c copy test.mp4

ffmpeg version N-88514-gd5995c531d Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavformat    58.  0.102 / 58.  0.102
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.101 /  7.  0.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'origin.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  Duration: 03:55:00.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1414 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 1343 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.0.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, q=2-31, 1343 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 4921 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   26141kB time=00:03:16.72 bitrate=1088.6kbits/s speed=1.68e+003x
video:24412kB audio:1569kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.619153%
```

Comment: Share the console readout of `ffmpeg -i file.mp4`. What's the file size?

Comment: @Gyan it's about 2.3 GB.

Comment: We need the output that Gyan is requesting to be able to suggest anything.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard t's updated. sorry for missing all the details earlier.